# Disable spacebar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created an **image gallery** in php using mysql. It has the capability to **add comments** by user.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUZpm.png)

My problem here is that whenever i try **pressing a spacebar** in my message box, it changes the image and im not able to enter more than one word in my message box.

Is it because of my code?? Or is it a default behavior?? If so, how can i stop it??

Comment: Does it change the image right away (without submitting), or when you submit the comment?

Comment: Why does it change the image when you press the spacebar?

Comment: It changes it right away even before i submit the comment

Comment: That has nothing to do with the spacebar, you need to learn about HTML and CSS so you can create templates which do what you need them to do.

Comment: @Lex: Thats what i dont know

Comment: ok, and how do you want us to take a look at things if you dont post anyOof your code? You want us to _guess_ your code and tell you what you have to change? *Always* include your mthml markup, the css definitions and your php code to questions. Best as far reduced to the actual problem, so without any ballast.

Comment: @markus-tharkun: You dont have to be rude for that. i have created this page with the best of my knowledge in HTML and CSS. If you can help me, I appreciate it. If not you dont have to be rude on someone who is seeking help.

Comment: @arkascha: Im sorry. I was confused whether its because of my code or ts a default behavior. Thats why I posted a sceenshot.

Comment: A screenshot does not help at all, sorry. And to make that clear: pressing the space bar inside some text input is a totally valid thing to do, no special behaviour is triggered by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is the answer. I had to set

> enableKeyboard=false

in ready function as it is by default true.

You can refer the link below for further details:

[Photo Swipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/)

Thanks for no help..:P